# How can I addClass this Button in OnClientClick event

Tags: javascript, asp.net

How can I addClass this Button in OnClientClick event.

**I have a list of 2 buttons:**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpt_one" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
<ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Button ID="bt_falist" ClientIDMode="Static" OnClientClick='<%# "handleLikeClick("11", "22"); return false;" %>' Text="&#xf004;" />
      <label id="countlike"><%# Eval("CountF") %></label>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I try to addClass for button's event. **However when I click on the 2nd button it addsClass to the first button**

```
function handleLikeClick(videoId, id) {
    // Perform your like button logic here
    /*alert(videoId);*/
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "...",
        data: JSON.stringify({ videoId: videoId, id: id }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            //$(this).addClass("fas colorred");
            $('#bt_falist').addClass("fas colorred");
            $('#bt_falist').removeClass("far");
            var txt = document.getElementById("countlike").innerHTML;
            var num = parseInt(txt) + 1;
            document.getElementById("countlike").innerHTML = num;
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(error.responseText);
        }
    });

    // Prevent postback
    return false;
};
```

Even though I try to use: `$(this).addClass()` but it still gives the same result.

Looking forward to a solution. Thank you

Comment: Your buttons can't share the same ID - IDs must be unique on the page. Maybe identify them with classes or [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that both the button have the same *ID*. To solve the issue, you can use *class* attribute like the following way:

**HTML:**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpt_one" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Button CssClass="my-button" OnClientClick='<%# "handleLikeClick("11", "22"); return false;" %>' Text="&#xf004;" />
    <label class="like-count"><%# Eval("CountF") %></label>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

**JS:**

```
function handleLikeClick(videoId, id) {
  var $button = $(event.target).closest('.my-button');
  var $countLabel = $button.next('.like-count');

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "...",
    data: JSON.stringify({ videoId: videoId, id: id }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (response) {
      $button.addClass("fas colorred");
      $button.removeClass("far");
      var count = parseInt($countLabel.text()) + 1;
      $countLabel.text(count);
    },
    error: function (error) {
      alert(error.responseText);
    }
  });

  return false; //prevent postback
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For a gridview, repeater, listview etc.?

Then for repeating controls, each control (with runat=server) will receive a custom ID. This is required, since then how would you know or distinguish the difference between controls on each row? And you can't have on a page multiple controls with the same id - that's not allowed.

The most simple way is to PASS the current button in your function.

So, then this:

```
<asp:Button CssClass="my-button" 
   OnClientClick='<%# "handleLikeClick(this, "11", "22"); return false;" %>'
      Text="&#xf004;" />
```

So, now in your function, you can do this:

```
            function handleLikeClick(btn, videoId, id) {
                var $button = $(btn);
                var $countLabel = $button.next('.like-count');

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "...",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ videoId: videoId, id: id }),
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (response) {
                        $button.addClass("fas colorred");
                        $button.removeClass("far");
                        var count = parseInt($countLabel.text()) + 1;
                        $countLabel.text(count);
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        alert(error.responseText);
                    }
                });

                return false; //prevent postback
            }
```

So, pass the button via "this".

Remember, a button or ANY control in a data repeater (repeater, listview, gridview) will be given a row number. In fact in most cases it will be given the control name, button name, and then row number.

So the button id becomes GridView_myButtonid_01 etc.

But, you don't have to much care, since passing this will solve that issue.